# Styled-component warning suggesting I use `attrs` method even though I am?

Tags: reactjs, parallax, styled-components

I had a styled component that was rendering 3 times, each having a parallax effect.

```js
const ParallaxContainer = styled.section`
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.3;
  bottom: ${props => props.bottomValue}px;
`;
```

The parallax is achieved by updating the `bottom` value every scrollEvent through a pretty expensive calculation. Meaning, this component is getting re-rendered very often.

Unsurprisingly, I was getting the warning `Over 200 classes were generated for component styled.section. Consider using the attrs method, together with a style object for frequently changed styles.` So I tried to follow the advice, and refactored the component to this:

```js
const ParallaxContainer = styled.section.attrs(
  ({ bottomValue }) => ({
    style: {
      bottom: bottomValue + "px"
    }
  })
)`
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.3;
`;
```

But I am still getting the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Sandbox demonstrating my issue: https://codesandbox.io/embed/styled-components-is-yelling-at-me-attrs-zhnof

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is the lines you left commented out in your style. Remember, your style is just a template string. The CSS-style commented lines are only ignored after the string has been interpolated and passed to Styled Components.

The `Over 200 classes` error happened in the first place because the style string needed to be re-computed on every scroll event, which results in a completely new styled component instance. Moving it to `attrs` is like defining the style in JS in the old-fashioned React way, so these styles don't go through Styled Components.

Comment: Awesome, I actually wasn't aware that comments inside template strings still get passed through. This makes a lot more sense now. Thanks!

Comment: I just avoid using styled components in this case.